# Visor/Car Vocabulary

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, verbs, vocabulary

Is it correct to say pull down the visor? Can we use put up to describe the opposite action?

I have already tried google to find the answer and I came upon pull down, put down and drop, but I could not find anything on the opposite action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pull down the sun visor, and put the sun visor up.

There are lots of idiomatic ways to say this. Perhaps "fold down" and "fold away".

You should probably usually say "sun visor", as "visor" (without modification) usually means a transparent (or perforated) face-shield, such as on a motorcycle helmet. You can see through a visor, you can't see through a sun visor.

Comment: For all you know, OP may *mean* "visor" in the sense of the sunshield on a motorbike helmet. Besides, the same applies to both.